# Are either the Stargate Atlantis: Legacy novels or Stargate Atlantis: Back to Pegasus comic books official canon continuations of the show?

Tags: stargate, canon, stargate-atlantis

*Stargate Atlantis* ended after five seasons, but there are currently two storylines that tell the tale of what happened afterwards.

The first storyline was the eight novel series *[Stargate Atlantis: Legacy](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_Atlantis:_Legacy)*, published from 2010 to 2015. In this series, Atlantis returns to the Pegasus Galaxy only to find that all the Wraith are uniting under a single queen who called herself "Death"*.

More recently is the comic series *[Stargate Atlantis: Back to Pegasus](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_Atlantis:_Back_to_Pegasus_1)*, published in 2016. In this series, Atlantis also returns to the Pegasus Galaxy, but instead they find the [mysterious alien species](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Unknown_Alien) first encountered in a parallel dimension in the episode *[The Daedalus Variations](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Daedalus_Variations)*.

These two series are mutually exclusive, since they both tell different stories of why Atlantis returned to the Pegasus Galaxy and what happened when they arrived. Have either of these been deemed to be official canon continuations of the show?

The [Stargate Wiki](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_Wiki) is no help, since it says that both storylines are canon, which they can't be.

<sup>* Personally, I found the idea of Wraith giving themselves names to be ridiculous, since they were all nameless in the show (except for the ones that the Atlantis team named, like Todd). But that's beside the point.</sup>

Comment: Per [Joseph Mallozzi](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/may-17-2011-stargate-universe-season-2-the-blockade-bubble-bath-sequence-and-another-mucho-mailbag/) "*Answer: I suppose it depends on the fan.  Given the fact that it’s unlikely we’ll see any new adventures of SG-1, Atlantis, or Universe, then **why not consider the books canon if it allows the characters to live on?*"**

Comment: I haven't read either one of these, but is it possible that Atlantis returned to Pegasus *twice*?  (Returning to our galaxy in between the two sojourns.)  This could be the case, for example, if neither of these stories explicitly stated which "Earth Years" they occurred in or how long they stayed exactly.  The publication dates given would seem to allow it, if we're just going to assume it happened in the years the stories were published.

Comment: To be canon the series would have to have been "approved" by the current owner." i.e. the new star wars movies are canon because disney owns the rights now. If both of these series are "official" then all bets are off. Typically it is said that the most recent are the "official canon" pieces, but some just say that nothing outside of the series is canon. you will never get a straight answer on this. It always depends on who you talk to. Personally,I say that anything "official" is "canon" even if they contradict. it was approved by the owner so even if it differs; doesnt mean it never happened